# Is there any way to identify heading and paragraph from scanned images using tensorflow object detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

i need to identify heading and paragraphs from scanned images. is there any better way to identify this?

i already tried ssd_inception_v2 model, but it is not accurate.

Comment: Have you tried anything from there? https://paperswithcode.com/task/scene-text-detection

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea would be to train a network itself in order to solve the problem, you won't need a huge model for it. The labelling part of the input dataset though might be annoying. Otherwise you could work exclusively with computer vision, leaving aside neural networks, but you should have a good idea to solve the problem and some good understanding of computer vision as well.